# Why is this mission not complete?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm fairly new to KSP and it took me a **long** time to finally figure out how to play the damn game because without science you can't get better rockets and without better rockets you can't get into space to get science. However I finally figured out all about EVA travel from the launch pad and got enough science that I can finally perform suborbital flights. With that I had finally found a source of funds and science which I could farm: ferrying rich people into suborbital space repeatedly.

Unfortunately my most recent mission put my kerbals into a weird state. When I go to the launch pad there are no tourists available to put into my rocket, but I still have this mission active.

[image: Incomplete Mission]

I can't figure out why this mission is still considered incomplete. As you can see, they only have a single destination on their itinerary and they were sent there successfully. This is probably the 7th time I've done this mission (sending rich people into suborbital space) and I never had this issue before.

Comment: What happened when you attempted that mission for the first time? Did you bring the tourists back safely, for example? Is the flight still ongoing?

Comment: I completed the flight safely, however there was a single oddity with the landing. I'm not very good at controlling my rockets yet so I just shoot straight up in the air and fall straight back down, activating parachutes as necessary. On this flight we happened to land very, **very** high up in the mountains, so we touched down within seconds of the parachutes activating and the next 10 minutes were spent slowly sliding down the mountain. The video display in the bottom-right showed the tourists were still alive, though.

Comment: Did you recover the pod or is it still at the base of the mountain?

Comment: How would I check? To my knowledge the only way to get back to the space station and launch another rocket is to hit the recover button. I haven't figured out a way to control two rockets at once yet.

Comment: You can return to the space center from the pause menu, without ending your current flight. You can check your ongoing flights from the Tracking Station at the space center.

Comment: Sure enough, the ship is still stranded out in the middle of the mountains. Looks like I also had an old science ship sitting in the ocean for the last week, too.

Comment: You can also find out the status of the Kerbal tourists in the Astronaut Center, if you're confused about where they might be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though the objectives don't explicitly mention this, you have to return your passengers to the space center in order for their journey to count as complete.

You can check ongoing flights from the space center's tracking station. Any vessel or Kerbal that's landed on Kerbin and not under acceleration can be recovered by pressing the button at the top of the screen.

Comment: It's good practice to recover your spaceships right after you touch down anyway.  You get money from it, as well as any science stored on the ship, and the crew return to the rotation for future missions.

Comment: Note for new players: you don't have to go to the tracking center for this.  When your ship is able to be recovered (landed safely on Kerbin, not accelerating), you can mouse over the altimeter at the top of the screen and a "Recover Vessel" option will drop down.

Comment: @Cody You have to go to the tracking center to switch to a different vessel. That's what I meant.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer: If we're being pedantic, even that's not strictly necessary. You can switch vessels by clicking them in the map mode and selecting "switch to". And of course, if they're close enough to your current vessel, you can also use the next/previous vessel hotkeys (`[` and `]` by default).